# KDB/Q: How to combine/append tables?

Tags: kdb

This is a simple question but I cannot figure out.
I have several tables with the same columns. How do I combine them into 1 big table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:

If tables' schema is completely identical use [`raze`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/raze/)

```
raze (t1;t2;t3;...)
```

This approach is more efficient.

But if schemas have differences use [`uj`](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/uj/)

```
(uj/) (t1;t2;t3;...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that you will often see "raze" implemented with alternative syntax (join over):

```
(,/) (t1;t2;t3)
```

And if the case where you are only combining two tables, a simple comma will join them:

```
t1,t2
```